# Library to parse SVG in Ruby or Python

Tags: python, ruby, svg

SVG is a huge standard, which is based on XML. I have parsed SVG as XML in the past. However, some things are hard.

For example, I would like to know the size of a group. As far as I can tell, this is only possible by recursively stepping through all the children in the group (noting all their transformations) and accumulating their sizes.

I would love to have a library that could do stuff like that for me. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python you have [pysvg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysvg/0.2.1):

```
import pysvg.parser

svg = pysvg.parser.parse(<filename>)
print svg.get_width(), svg.get_height()
```

Comment: I found this library difficult to understand and use based on the docs: http://packages.python.org/pysvg/. Are you familiar with any other documentation/tutorials for it?

Comment: @Chris I'm afraid I'm not aware of any other reference. There are a couple of examples in the author's [blog](http://www.codeboje.de/tag/pysvg/), but they aren't really self-explanatory.

Comment: WHen I tried to do this, it tells me :
"svg = pysvg.parser.parse("mapexample.svg")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parser'"
Any clues ?

Comment: This error message looks like your import statement is `import pysvg` when it should be `import pysvg.parser`.

Comment: Just passed by to say that I found this http://www.sew-brilliant.org/pysvg/index.html