# Python - Read rectangles from and .svg file

Tags: python-2.7, svg

I have several groundtruth files generated from inkspace with .svg format. In order to verify the precision of my program written in python, I need to read the 'rect' fields from the .svg files, them coordinates and the other attributes, such as contour color, and id.

I found this topic:
[Library to parse SVG in Ruby or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534265/library-to-parse-svg-in-ruby-or-python)

where is suggested to use the pysvg library, but I can't find the documentation about the psvg.parser.parse module.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: parser.parse reads in the file. What do you actually want to know here?

Comment: I want to read the 'rect' fields like this one:

  <rect
     style="fill:#ff0000"
     id="rect3346"
     width="110.23089"
     height="43.244427"
     x="71.226112"
     y="28.829618" />

I need to read all the rectangles inside the svg file, with its coordinates and the color in python. How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use python xml parser, since svg is a type of an xml. Use `xpath` or `findall` to extract the elements you want and read the element attributes to extract the information you need:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

# for parsing svg as a string:
svg = ET.fromstring(svg_string)
# for parsing svg from a file:
svg = ET.parse(svg_file)

rects = svg.findall('rect')

for rect in rects:
    width = rect.attrib['width']
    height = rect.attrib['height']
    x = rect.attrib['x']
    y = rect.attrib['y']
```

Keep in mind that if the `rect` elements are parts of groups, you have to also parse the transformations of all the groups they belong to. This can get quite tricky.